# Direct incoming port 80 traffic to local virtual host

Tags: apache, mamp-pro

I am running MAMP Pro on a Mac and I have port forwarding set up on my router to forward traffic to my server.    For now I just have an IP for my computer, no domain name or DNS setup, although I could do that.  What I want to do is forward incoming traffic to a particular virtual host on my server.  e.g.  MAMP has a localhost by default.  I have a number of other virtual hosts, xxxx.local, and I would like to forward to a particular one.  Can I do that by editing httpd.config or the hosts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache "sees" the "host name" of the incoming request and forwards it to the virtual host with the same same. All other requests are captured from "localhost".
It's called "single link multihoming",means one IP address for a lot of virtual hosts.

Greetings,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I actually just pointed one of my domains to my home server IP and that works since it has a domain name and I have a local virtual host setup.  My original question was whether it is possible to do something like that if you just have an IP (i.e. can you send all requests to an IP to a particular single local virtual host rather than to the default localhost), and I guess the simple answer is no.  It forwards those to the localhost.